# Add a "Download Product-Informations in a PDF" Button to a product page

Tags: magento-1.8, products, product-page

I have a question, I want to add information pdfs to every of my products. How can I add a button for that on every product page?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched magento connect for product files and attachments? Do you need an extension or code sample?

Answer (score 1):

i) Create a **custom attribute named pdf** with **input type as TEXT** field.

ii) Then goto each product and give the filename

ii) Places the PDF files in the Media directory.

iii) Then goto catalog-> product-> view file..

iv) you can call the pdf in view.phtml file like

```
echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$_product->getAttributeText('pdf');
```

Hope it will work.

Have a nice day

Comment: There is no view.phtml file. I just can go to catalog -> product and there are a lot of directories with just one letter as name...

Comment: It looks like this now: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wo0g2gcjwdgtyn/PDF.jpg

Comment: Where I have to add this code? Somewhere?

Comment: The file path is 

app\design\frontend\your package\your theme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml.  
         

Your Package - Your current package.  
Your Theme - Your current theme.                   



If the file or folder not exists,  
Copy the file from             
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml                    



 and paste in              



app\design\frontend\your package\your theme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different free extensions around, but as an example one which one of my clients has tried which seems reasonable is [this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-attachments-extension.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by creating a File Type Product Attribute. By default, magento doesn't support this, but there are some free modules that do the trick. [Here's](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/file-attributes.html) one for example

Comment: but if you have the latest version it isnt working. :(